# Ошибка Nginx при работе плагина Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx

При работе wordpress’а (в частности плагин Contact Form) появляется ошибка:

> 2015/04/16 16:09:36 [error] 17340#0: *48878 upstream timed out (110:
>   Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: ххх.хх.х.хх, server: мойсайт.ru, request: "POST
>   /internet-priyomnaya/ HTTP/1.0", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "мойсайт.ru", referrer:
>   "http://мойсайт.ru/internet-priyomnaya/"

Answer (score 1):

Ваш Nginx обрабатывает запросы с помощью PHP-FPM (что явно видно из логов), поэтому решение с `proxy_read_timeout` вряд ли поможет. Для увеличения времени ожидания от PHP-FPM необходимо установить переменную `fastcgi_read_timeout` на необходимую величину (в примере 300 секунд):

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

Стандартно Nginx ждет 30 секунд.

Более подробно можете посмотреть в [этой статье](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/increase-script-execution-time/).

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что по умолчанию в конфигурации стоит время ожидания 60 сек, скорей всего Ваш запрос выполняется дольше из-за этого вылетает

В конфиге укажите

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  мойсайт.домен;

    location / {
        ...
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Описание параметра с оф.сайта

Синтаксис:  proxy_read_timeout время;

```
Умолчание:  
proxy_read_timeout 60s;
Контекст:   http, server, location
Задаёт таймаут при чтении ответа проксированного сервера. Таймаут устанавливается не на всю передачу ответа, а только 
между двумя операциями чтения. Если по истечении этого времени проксируемый сервер ничего не передаст, соединение
 закрывается.
```

После изменения конфигурации не забываем выполнять `# service nginx restart`